# How to resolve "no usable dependency style found" error while making GCC 4.9.1

Tags: linux, gcc

I want to install gcc 4.9.1. So I downloaded the tar ball, installed the dependencies, and ran config with -

`./configure --program-suffix=-4.9.1 --disable-multilib`

That worked fine.

But when I took the next step and fired `make`, I got the following error:

```
configure: error: no usable dependency style found
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
```

The error comes when `make` is trying to `checking dependency style of /usr/bin` and it finds `none`.

Can any one explain what is meant by `checking dependency style of /usr/bin` ?

Any idea when this issue comes and how to resolve it. I did some searching, could not find anything.

I am compiling on a 64 bit RHEL 6.x machine.

> EDIT 1:

As advised by arm, I grepped for the error in the individual config.log's. Finally found it in one. Here are some contents

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/ext/hash_map:60,
                 from conftest.cpp:74:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
configure:8747: $? = 0
configure:8747: result: yes
configure:8794: checking dependency style of /usr/bin
configure:8825: trying gcc3
| depmode=gcc3 source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 115: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying gcc
| depmode=gcc source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 138: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying hp
| depmode=hp source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 138: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying sgi
| depmode=sgi source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 179: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying aix
| depmode=aix source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 237: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying icc
| depmode=icc source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 285: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying hp2
| depmode=hp2 source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 322: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying tru64
| depmode=tru64 source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 384: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying dashmstdout
| depmode=dashmstdout source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 415: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying dashXmstdout
| depmode=dashXmstdout source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 415: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying makedepend
| depmode=tru64 source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 384: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying dashmstdout
| depmode=dashmstdout source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 415: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying dashXmstdout
| depmode=dashXmstdout source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 415: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying makedepend
| depmode=makedepend source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 467: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying cpp
| depmode=cpp source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 518: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying msvisualcpp
| depmode=msvisualcpp source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 561: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8825: trying msvcmsys
| depmode=msvcmsys source=sub/conftest.c object=sub/conftest.o depfile=sub/conftest.Po tmpdepfile=sub/conftest.TPo /bin/sh ./depcomp /usr/bin -c -o sub/conftest.o sub/conftest.c
configure:8868: failure, diagnostics are:
| ./depcomp: line 561: /usr/bin: is a directory
configure:8879: result: none
configure:8882: error: no usable dependency style found
```

Comment: You'll need to check config.log and scroll up further. This error is just a result of something failing before.

Comment: @rubenvb Like I said, the error is not coming from the configure command, rather from the make command. I don't see how scrolling further on the config.log could help me. Let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: There are multiple `configure` commands, and the ones in the subdirectories are called by `make`, based on what you pass to the top-level one.

Comment: @Wildling the fact that it is testing `/usr/bin` means some test above it failed. Post that last config.log you found in its entirety to something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so we can see what exactly is going wrong. Or never mind. Apparently you already found what it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. You should not build GCC in the source tree; it isn't explicitly disabled, but it is not supported. Try again with an external build directory. It's in the HTML install manual.
2. Check the `config.log` files. There will be one per directory, and one will contain the "no usable dependency style found" message. You should be able to find more details there.

EDIT following extra information:

It appears that you have set `CXX=/usr/bin` in your environment. It should be `CXX=/usr/bin/g++`.

Comment: Hey I tried a out of source build. Didnt help. Same error has come again. Also, can you please clarify what you mean by "There will be a config.log file per directory". Which directories exactly ?

Comment: `find . -name config.log` -- those directories.

Comment: I have updated the questions with the details you advised. Can you please take a look at it once. I am unable to deduce what the problem might be.

Comment: Answer updated. If that's not the problem, please post the output of `env`.

Answer (score 6):

On `CentOS/RedHat`, it's very likely because you don't have **g++** installed

```
$ which g++
// not found
```

---

Installing the **`Development Tools`** will solve this issue:

```
$ yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
```